# Automatic type conversion through constructors with overloaded operator functions

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class rec
{
private:
    float l;
    float w;
public:
    rec(): l(0) , w(0) {}
    rec(float a)
    {
        l = a;
        w = 0.0;
    }
    rec(float a, float b): l(a) , w(b) {}
    friend rec operator +(rec& , rec&);
    //friend rec operator +(float , rec&);
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream&, rec&);
};

ostream& operator <<(ostream& out , rec& r3)
{
    out << "l " << r3.l << endl << "w " << r3.w;
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    rec r1(8, 3) , r2(2,7) , r3;
    r3 = 5.0 + r2;
    cout << "sum " << r3;
}

rec operator +(rec r1 , rec r2)
{
    float lsum , wsum;
    lsum = r1.l + r2.l;
    wsum = r1.w + r2.w;
    return rec(lsum , wsum);
}
```

I thought the point of automatic type conversion here was to make possible 
r3 = 5.0 + r2
where 5.0 is treated like an object to be used in the overloaded + and << functions making the   friend rec operator +(float , rec&);
unnecessary.
Maybe I am missing something here.

Comment: Oh yah. The compiler error is "error: no match for 'operator+' in '5.0e + r2'

Comment: Have your operators take references to `const rec`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems with your code. First, `friend rec operator +(rec& , rec&);` will declare an `operator+` which takes a non-const reference to it's arguments. Conversion from `float` to `rec` through constructor will produce a temporary, and non-const references can not bind to temporary. You should fix it by accepting arguments either by value, or by const reference.

Second problem is that definition of `operator+` does not match it's current declaration.

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you. Seems like a dumb mistake now that I see it. My teacher didn't talk about the non-const reference issue but it makes sense now that its pointed out to me.